# Python Dataset module error: You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, dataset, psycopg2

Having some difficulties to query data from a postgres db using python dataset module , my data is type varchar when i query the data i receive the following error.

**ERROR:**

LINE 1: ...t * from sources.product where post = 31055183...

HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
 [SQL: 'select * from sources.product where post = 310551835']

**snip of code used:**

```
deltas = db.query('select * from deltas.deltas_del')

for idx in deltas:
            print type(idx['post'])
            prod = db.query('select * from sources.product where post = 310551835')
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the value 310551835 in quotes, since product is supposed to be varchar?

Comment: @jlyoung Right , yes i did try that but same error returned.

Comment: Are you sure your where clause is correct?  Your error message says "post" but the snippet of code you posted says "post_full".  Try:  prod = db.query("select * from sources.product where post = '310551835'")

Comment: @jlyoung correct it was a matter of quotes " " in where clause

Comment: Cool. I'll write it up as an answer and you can accept the answerespond if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes to the value in the right hand side of the where clause since you're filtering by a varchar.

`prod = db.query("select * from sources.product 
where post = '310551835'"`